# Having trouble refreshing the Windows aero preview in C#

Tags: c#, windows, pinvoke, aero

I want to refresh the aero preview that's displayed when hovering over a taskbar icon on Windows (or when Alt+Tabbing).

I found a function called [`DwmInvalidateIconicBitmaps`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwmapi/nf-dwmapi-dwminvalidateiconicbitmaps) that seems promising, but when I use it:

```
[DllImport("dwmapi.dll")]
static extern int DwmInvalidateIconicBitmaps(IntPtr hwnd);
...
int res = DwmInvalidateIconicBitmaps(MyWindowHandle);
```

`res` gets set to `-2,147,024,809`. When I look at the hex it comes out to `FFFF FFFF 8007 0057`, which seems to correspond to `E_INVALIDARG` according to [this site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/common-hresult-values).

My window handle however is valid and is used in other places successfully. Another site I came across mentioned that this error can be thrown when the DLL couldn't be loaded. Could that be the issue?

I also doesn't see this function mentioned on the [pinvoke site](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/dwmapi.DwmUpdateThumbnailProperties) though I do see other DWM functions, which is odd.

Windows 10 / .NET Core

Comment: Does the window belong to your calling process?

Comment: @SimonMourier Well...no. I saw that in the docs too. Wasn't sure it that would cause the InvalidArg error..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwmapi/nf-dwmapi-dwminvalidateiconicbitmaps) clearly stipulates this:

> hwnd
>
> A handle to the window or tab whose bitmaps are being invalidated
> through this call. **This window must belong to the calling process**.

If this is not the case, you'll get an `E_INVALIDARG` error.